# Special characters UTF8 not displaying in Safari

Tags: safari, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I thought this was something easy to Google, but the answers I found, did not fix my problem

In Chrome my RSS feeds are looking like this

```
"Â¿QuÃ© es un serum antimanchas?"
```

But all the rest characters are ok ..

In Safari, is the opposite. This line looks fine, but the rest of characters are wrong... and they look like

```
Espect�culo
```

I have this on my header which is supposed to work, can't find the problem,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<head>

 
  <title>Pcweb</title>
  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

NOTE: All files are saved with encode for UTF8 in sublime editor.

Comment: My Safari 5.1.7 (on Windows) cannot display . I haven't figured out how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see in Chrome is UTF-8 encoded data misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 encoded. For example, U+00BF “¿” is 0xC2 0xBF in UTF-8. Treating that as ISO-8859-1 data, you get U+00C2 “Â” U+00BF “¿”.

From the given data, it is impossible to say what goes wrong. My guess is that the data is sent with an HTTP `Content-Type` header that declares the encoding as ISO-8859-1. The URL would be needed to verify this hypothesis.

The character “�” indicates a data error at the character level: the data contains a byte that does not denote any character, or part of a multi-byte representation of a character, in the character encoding being applied. This is most often encountered when ISO-8859-1 is being misinterpreted as UTF-8 encoded.

It seems that the data contains a mix of UTF-8 encoded data and ISO-8859-1 encoded data. The fix is to modify the system so that it consistently uses UTF-8 throughout, or at least converts everything to UTF-8 when data is being composed to be sent to a user agent.